# sending messages and facebook application request to non-friend (anyone on facebook) through code (API) 

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

1. Can I send Facebook Message to a non-friend on facebook with API, with my account credentials ? 2. Can I create an facebook app and send application request to non-friend ?

Comment: @remus correct ! I am developing this as a research project in my school. the idea is to develop a search engine for social networks to find old students of school and their current information :(

Answer (score 0):

Not really.  You could send a friend request and then if accepted send the message.

Comment: thanks for quick reply. 
actually I am working on research project for uni and I know the things I am trying to do is not quit possible.
Do you have any idea that whether its allowed to send friend request through code ? I mean in this way I can send friend request to 1000 users !! 
And If I create an app on facebook then can I send app request to non-freinds ??

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot send facebook messages at all via the API. Even to your friends.
2. No, Per https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/  App request can only be sent only to user's friends.  This is done for privacy reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is the Facebook Send Dialog (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/) which permits you to send messages to batches of up to 50 users at a time. This is not fully automatable, since it displays a dialog and you need to fill in the message (copy/paste works) and click OK.

Facebook Send Dialog is exposed in Facebook PowerShell Module (http://facebookpsmodule.codeplex.com) as Show-FBMessageDialog. Note that even one non-friend in the list will invalidate the whole batch of users, so consider using the -FriendsOnly option.

As for sending messages to non-friends, Facebook prohibits this, presumably due to the obvious potential for abuse.

Comment: thanks for your answer. well I am doing all this to create a search engine and I have to send messages to non-friends. I can understand why Facebook prohibits this and I am completely agree with them. 
So there is no way an facebook app can send its own app request to users on facebook and you have to be friends with someone to send them an app request, right ?

Comment: AFAIK that is correct. You can't send an app request, friend request etc to a non-friend for the same reason you can't send a message; spammers would have a field day. How are you identifying the users who should receive this? Maybe you have some other way to reach them.

Comment: that is the point. there is no way I can identify limited number of persons who should receive message or app request because I am only getting "first name" "last name" "gender info (if user has made it public)" "profile pic" with my search call from FB API. So I have only one option to send that to everyone from result set, and this surely sounds like a SPAM and I know it. :(